# Setting an attribute from element contents

Tags: jquery

Lets say you have this:

```
<ul>
  <li>[foo] more stuff here</li>
  <li>[bar] stuff here</li>
  <li>[123] stuff here</li>
</ul>
```

and you want this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">more stuff here</li>
  <li id="bar">stuff here</li>
  <li id="123">stuff here</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, what's the simplest way to get this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yep. The selected answer below works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
    $li = $(this);
    var text = $li.text();
    var id = text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.indexOf("]"));
    $li.attr("id", id).text(text.replace("[" + id + "]", ""));
});
```

---

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/FDTcj/

---

fiddle with other brackets: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/FDTcj/1/

Answer (score 0):

jquery alone won't do this, you'll need to parse the contents. Personally I would use regular expressions:

```
$("li").each() {
    var regex = /\[([^\]]+)\] (.*)/;
    var matches = regex.exec($(this).html());
    $(this).attr("id", matches[1]);
    $(this).html(matches[2]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using regex.- [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FYyEP/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul').children().each(function(){
        $strVal=$(this).text();
        //extracting the required id value.
        var $idVal=((/\[.*\]/g.exec($strVal)).toString()).replace(/(?:\[|\])/g,"");
        $(this).html($strVal.replace(/\[.*\]/g,""));
        alert($idVal);
        $(this).attr('id',$idVal);
    });
});
```